# Draw Rect Monotouch PaintCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to make a better UI for my application but I'm stuck in this. My designing skills aren't good so I'm trying PaintCode.
I want to make a Login Screen with this shadow beneath the group of username and password.

[image: Shadowed UiView]

I can't use a UIView so I made the same but in PaintCode using a Rect.

```
var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
//// Shadow Declarations
var shadow = UIColor.DarkGray.ColorWithAlpha(0.71f).CGColor;
var shadowOffset = new SizeF(6.1f, 4.1f);
var shadowBlurRadius = 5.0f;

   //// Rectangle Drawing
 UIBezierPath rectanglePath = new UIBezierPath();
 rectanglePath.MoveTo(new PointF(18.0f, 239.0f));
 rectanglePath.AddLineTo(new PointF(383.0f, 239.0f));
 rectanglePath.AddLineTo(new PointF(383.0f, 13.0f));
 rectanglePath.AddLineTo(new PointF(18.0f, 13.0f));
 rectanglePath.AddLineTo(new PointF(18.0f, 239.0f));
 rectanglePath.ClosePath();
 context.SaveState();
 context.SetShadowWithColor(shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadow);
 UIColor.White.SetFill();
 rectanglePath.Fill();
 context.RestoreState();
```

Now I don't know what to do with that code. In the tutorials and documentation they usually make a UIView so they just subclass a UIView and add it in Interface Builder, that way you can always know exactly where the object is going to end in your final app. I don't know what to subclass and how to make the rect I draw beneath my username and password boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom class inheriting from UIView, then override Draw function and put your custom code there.

```
[Register("DrawView")]
public class DrawView : UIView
{
    public override void Draw(System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
    {
```

In the above sample the Register attribute is necessary if you want to use your control from XCode designer (or Xamarin Storyboard designer).